# Git: contents of repository directory with file info

Tags: git

I would think this is a relatively straightforward request, but it doesn't seem to be. For a given directory in my repository, I need to show a list of files (including directories) in that directory. Alongside each file, I need to show additional info - e.g. the datetime of the last commit for that file. This is for a simple repository viewer - cf. github.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any porcelain-level command that does this.  (Please let me know in another answer if there is, I'll delete this one) If I understand you properly, what you want to do is akin to the inner working of `git annotate`, only at file-within-a-path level instead of line-within-a-file.

The core logic isn't too hard to reproduce in a script.

Or you can cheat and just extract the information from `git log`. The only trick is to do it once per file, else it merges the commits.

```
for file in $(git ls-files); do
    echo $(git log --format=%ad -- $file | head -1) $file
done
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm specifically looking for a way of doing it without performing n+1 git commands because that is painfully, painfully slow. I'm starting to think the only way I can do this is to cache the results and update that cache via a git hook, which seems crazy for such a basic requirement; maybe that's how github, bitbucket, etc. do it, though.

Comment: Realistically, not count the git commands, you're still requesting information that's not available in an O(1) call.  I had a draft of git diff-tree'ing up a branch, but that's way slower than just git log.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Presumably, "git log -1 ..." in your loop would be a fair bit faster?

Comment: That's it! That's the option I failed to find in the git log help when I initially wrote this! Much better than the pipe indeed!